# Description of Keyword is empty - Tridion Anguilla framework

Tags: cme, content-manager

I am creating dropdown values for my customization. The attribute 'value' in options is empty "". I am loading the KeywordObj . can anyone help?

Here's my code -

```
 var keywordObj = $models.getItem(tcmId);
                    var desc = "";
                    if (keywordObj) {
                        function onKeywordLoaded() {
                            $evt.removeEventHandler(keywordObj, "load", onKeywordLoaded);
                            desc = keywordObj.getDescription();
                        }
                        if (keywordObj.isLoaded(true)) {
                            onKeywordLoaded();
                        }
                        else {
                            $evt.addEventHandler(keywordObj, "load", onKeywordLoaded);
                            keywordObj.load();
                        }
                    }
                    var opt = new Option(title, desc);
                    opt.setAttribute("tcmid", tcmId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how JavaScript works (async)

The assignment `var opt = new Option(title, desc);` happens (most of the time) *before* the call to `keywordObj.load()` has finished. So the `desc` variable is still empty if you want to use it there.

The easiest solution is to move these 2 lines:

```
var opt = new Option(title, desc);
opt.setAttribute("tcmid", tcmId);
```

inside the `onKeywordLoaded` callback.